# Uso del operador ternario

Tags: javascript

Quiero usar operador ternario con dos condiciones

```js
 var flag=true;
 var cont=45;
 
 (flag? && cont>0)  this.cont+=45:this.cont-=45;
```

en mi ejemplo se muestra que el operador ternario esta usando dos condiciones  (flag? && flag>0), **es posible usar dos condiciones?**

Pero sale error, como lo corrijo?

Comment: No asignes en expresiones ternarias; en su lugar, retorna valores: `cont = flag && cont > 0 ? cont + 45 : cont - 45`. Tampoco uses `var`, usa `const` si no piensas cambiar el valor de la variable o `let` si puede cambiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma correcta de usar el operador ternario es esta.

```
condición ? expr1 : expr2
```

En tu caso sería así.

```
 var flag=true;
 var cont=45;

 (flag && cont>0) ? (this.cont+=45) : (this.cont-=45);
```

Answer (score 3):

El operador ternario es, como su propio nombre indica, **un operador**. Por lo tanto, se usa en *expresiones*. Y ya sabemos que **toda expresión ha de devolver algo**.

En tu caso, como parece que **no quieres usar** el resultado final de `this.cont`, la forma correcta sería:

```
this.cont += ( flag && ( cont > 0 ) ) ? 45 : -45;
```